# HTML/CSS IE not showing header

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

My new website features a navigation built into and **overlapping** the header image.  Sadly, in internet explorer (All version < 10), both my header and navigation are simply **gone**.  Everything programmed with classic row-by-row HTML seems to work fine. 
I have tried the doc-type fixes, no avail.
I tried messing with my current numbers, nothing.

This is the CSS for the header: (Php selects random image)

```
Header 
   {
      height: 128px;
      background: url(<?php echo $selectedBg ?>);
      text-indent: -9999px;
      border-bottom: 0px solid #00;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0;
   }
```

And for the navigation: (Simple  used inside this class)

```
div.navigation
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 81px; left: 425px;
   height: 47px; width:575px;
   background-color: transparent;
   z-index: 10;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0;
   margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Announcement CSS:

```
div.announcement{
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px; left: 425px;
    height: 47px; width:575px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

All I need to do is make this show correctly in all browsers.  Thank you to anyone who can help.

**REQUESTED CODE SNIPPET:**

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<?php
  $bg = array('images/header1.png', 'images/header2.png', 'images/header3.png', 'images/header4.png', 'images/header5.png', 'images/header6.png', 'images/header7.png', 'images/header8.png' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = $bg[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>BitFracture.com</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/site.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/site.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="*" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    Header {
        height: 128px;
        background: url(<?php echo $selectedBg ?>);
        text-indent: -9999px;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #00;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
<div class="navigation"> 
    <a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/homeh.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/home.png'"></a> 
    <a href="#"><img src="images/repairs.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/repairsh.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/repairs.png'"></a> 
    <a href="#"><img src="images/articles.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/articlesh.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/articles.png'"></a> 
    <a href="#"><img src="images/software.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/softwareh.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/software.png'"></a> 
</div>
<div class="announcement">
    <p> <b>News:</b> Our new site is up and running!</p>
</div>
<header></header>
```

Comment: It might be that you're using an HTML tag (`<header>`) which is not recognized by older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is

```
Header 
   {...}
```

exactly? If you are using a `<header>` tag then delete it and replace the css header {} with div.header {} and apply it to a div tag like `<div class='header'>...</div>`

also #00; should be #000; (three colours, not 2 as that may give you funny results across different browsers).

You may also want to use a container element that has position:relative; set just to help browsers out on where to start positioning from.

Can you maybe post a working snippet of the html that the css goes with?

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have added the problematic code to the original question.

Comment: Also, making the changes above has removed the header completely from all browsers.  I am trying to make it work, by adding the <img> tag inside the div.header. (Update, that worked!  Thank you!)  
Just one more asking, why is the header showing slightly outside of the frame?

Comment: Well thanks anyway, somehow that only has problems on IE6, so most won't have that error.  IE7, 8, 9, and 10 do work, as well as forefox 3-17, and chrome.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about IE6 to be honest - many large sites like youtube have dropped support for it and the only organisations i've found still using IE6 is the local council :/

Comment: That is what I figured.  My only concern is that it is the default browser for XP machines, and some people (For some ungodly reason) don't update it.  But yes, thanks again.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about that, XP is going the same was as IE6. In fact, it's hard to even buy a disk with XP on anymore :(